# Keep getting null pointer exception

Tags: java

here is my program: basically i have an xml file and from that file i have to decode a base64 string but i keep getting NullPointerException..please help! code is as follows...

```
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import javax.xml.parsers.SAXParser;
import javax.xml.parsers.SAXParserFactory;
import org.xml.sax.Attributes;
import org.xml.sax.SAXException;
import org.xml.sax.helpers.DefaultHandler;
import org.apache.commons.codec.binary.Base64;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.util.Arrays;

public class main {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        SAXParserFactory parserFactor = SAXParserFactory.newInstance();
        SAXParser parser = parserFactor.newSAXParser();
        SAXHandler handler = new SAXHandler();
        //parser.parse(ClassLoader.getSystemResourceAsStream("ATMSPopulateDMSData.xml"), 
        // handler);
        parser.parse(new FileInputStream("C:\\Users\\qta6754\\workspace\\Java_Dev\\XML64_Decoded\\ATMSMessageData.xml"), handler);
        for (NeededInfo emp : handler.empList) {
            System.out.println(emp);
        }
    }
}

class SAXHandler extends DefaultHandler {
    List<NeededInfo> empList = new ArrayList<>();
    NeededInfo emp = null;
    String content = null;
    String did = null;

    public void startElement(String uri, String localName, String qName, Attributes attributes) throws SAXException {
        switch (qName) {
            case "dMSDeviceStatus":
                emp = new NeededInfo();
                emp.id = attributes.getValue("id");
                emp.Read();
                break;
        }
    }

    public void characters(char[] ch, int start, int length) throws SAXException {
        content = String.copyValueOf(ch, start, length).trim();
    }
}

class NeededInfo {
    String id;
    String firstName;
    String lastName;
    String location;
    String organization_id;
    String operator_id;
    String device_id;
    String dms_device_status;
    String dms_current_message;
    String last_comm_time;
    String date;
    String time;

    public String toString() {
        //return firstName + " " + lastName + "(" + id + ")" + location+date+time+device_name;
        return "Organization id: " + organization_id + "\n" + "Operator id: " + operator_id + "\n" + "Device id: " + device_id + "\n"
                + "Dms Device Status: " + dms_device_status + "\n" + "Dms Current Message: " + dms_current_message + "\n" + "Last Comm Time" + "\n"
                + "Time: " + time + "\n" + "Date: " + date + "\n" + "decoded string is: " + "\n" + "-------------------------------------";
    }

    public void Read() {
        byte[] byteArray = Base64.decodeBase64(dms_current_message.getBytes());
        String decodedString = new String(byteArray);
        System.out.print("The decoded message is:  " + decodedString);
        //                   return decodedString;
    }
}
```

Comment: At what line exactly?

Comment: Side note - for example in your `NeededInfo` class - you can declare multiple `String` on the same line: `String id, firstName, lastName, ...;` etc.  This will make your code look cleaner.

Comment: Also, please format your code with correct indentation etc. so it's easier to read.

Comment: Indeed, making your code human-readable makes it a lot easier to be debugged by, well, humans.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's hard to guess where you're getting your error, but I'm assuming here:

```
byte[] byteArray = Base64.decodeBase64(dms_current_message.getBytes());
```

I don't see `dms_current_message` being initialized ever, yet you're calling a method on it, which would definitely result in the null pointer exception.

Comment: yes but dms current message is a string which holds the base 64 coded string which needs to be decoded and displayed

Comment: @user3779673 I would recommend cleaning up this code immensely before attempting to debug. It's a mess just to look at it, and since you're using a lot of 3rd party stuff (or so it seems) I can't run it myself and try to figure it out. Either way, please let us know the line that you're having the issue on - if I did not guess it correctly - and I'm sure we can help more.

Comment: 52,25,140 are the lines

Comment: @user3779673 you're creating the "NeededInfo" object, setting the ID, and then attempting to Read(). You are literally never initializing dms_current_message, meaning it's going to be null. If you try to print it out on the line before, I bet it'd be null.

Comment: so what do you suggest i do to fix this?

Comment: @user3779673 well, you said that dms_current_message is supposed to hold an encoded string.. which string? Make sure that field gets that string, and that should fix your problem. It's extremely hard for any of us to help further without the whole codebase.

Comment: this is all the code..is is possible for you to provide a example?

Comment: is possible for you to provide a example?

Comment: @user3779673 dms_current_message = "hello world"; ... but in all seriousness, it completely depends on your application.

Comment: @user3779673 if it's not parsing your XML file properly, that's a completely different question. If my answer helped with this specific question, it'd be awesome if you could mark it and open a new question, and I could try to help there.

Answer (score 1):

Your `Read` method accesses the `dms_current_message` which is never initialized in all the code you included in your question.

```
byte[] byteArray = Base64.decodeBase64(dms_current_message.getBytes());
```